# Display array elements as normal CSV - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create comma separated list from array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php)

I have an array as follows;

`$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);`

I want to `print` or `echo` this variable as `1,2,3,4,5`. What is the simplest method for this?? I printed `array[0]` first and then skipped first value and used `foreach` function to echo all remaining `",".$value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
echo implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [implode function](http://php.net/manual/function.implode.php).

In the example you showed, it'd be written like this:

```
implode(',', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$result = implode(',', $array);
echo $result;
```