# How to transform array to comma separated words string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create comma separated list from array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php)

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
    [4] => amet
)
```

How to transform this to a string like this with php?

```
$string = 'lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet';
```

Answer (score 301, accepted):

```
$arr = array ( 0 => "lorem", 1 => "ipsum", 2 => "dolor");

$str = implode (", ", $arr);
```

Comment: What if is it array inside array.

Comment: Create a loop over the parent array or use array_map. @ankitsuthar

Answer (score 21):

Directly from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Comment: I used implode with a little modification. Since I needed a comma-separated list with single quotes as well, I used the following on my array: $innie = implode("', '", $arrayDistricts); [Note the single quotes inside the double quotes.] Then I used this in my query: IN ('$innie') [Note the single quotes around the variable.]

Comment: Thanks Kilo thats exactly what i was looking for. I am using it in a bulk update

Answer (score 19):

Make your array a variable and use implode.

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

`$string = implode(",", $array);`