# How to convert items in array to a comma separated string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create comma separated list from array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php)

Given this array:

```
$tags = array('tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4','...');
```

How do I generate this string (using PHP):

```
$tags = 'tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, ...';
```

Comment: did you google first before posting the question here??? :):)

Comment: I'd like to point out that Googling this problem brings you here to this page, so in effect this question is a self-fulfilling prophecy, as otherwise this page would not exist :)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/implode):

```
 $tags = implode(', ', array('tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4'));
```

Comment: This is a bad idea if you're trying to create reliable CSV strings. CSV has rules regarding commas inside fields, etc..

Answer (score 25):

Yes you can do this by using [implode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$string = implode(', ', $tags);
```

And just so you know, there is an alias of *implode*, called [join](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

```
$string = join(', ', $tags);
```

I tend to use join more than implode as it has a *better* name (a more self-explanatory name :D )

Comment: And the good thing is that both takes the almost same time to execute :) I made a benchmark

Comment: Coming back at this after 5 years, I now tend to use `implode` instead of `join`, not sure why, but I find that explode-implode is more common in most codebases I've worked on now, and I prefer to align myself with the rest of the codebase in order to maintain a certain level of consistency.

Answer (score 13):

Use PHP function [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on your array

```
$mystring = implode(', ',$tags)
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply implode:

```
$tags = implode(", ", $tags);
```