# display data from selected checkbox

Tags: php

I am beginner in PHP I'm trying to generate PDF but I have trouble in how can I display data from selected checkbox. For example I want to select two rows or three or four using this `select * from table where id in ($stk)` but its displays blank.

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='stick[]' id="stick" value =' <?php echo $row['id']; ?>'        /> 


    $name = isset($_POST['stick'])?$_POST['stick']:NULL; 
    if(isset($_POST['stick'])){ 
             foreach ($name as $stk){

             $query = "SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo in($stk)";  
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $controlnumber = $query_row['MENo'];
    $assetname = $query_row['machine_equipments_name']; 
    $location = $query_row['Location'];    

$text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", "Koushin Mechatronics Manufacturing Philippines Inc. ", '                                   PROPERTY STICKER', 'Control No.     :    '. $controlnumber .' ', 'Asset Name    :    '. $assetname .' ',  'Location          :   '. $location .' ');}
```

Comment: `**SELECT` why do you put `**` here?

Comment: omit the `**`? in your query

Comment: never mind the ** i allready removed look this example this "SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo in(1,2,3)" it is correct but when i put variable  "SELECT * FROM machine_and_equipments where MENo in($stk)" its freaking me how can i suppose to put value  with comma 1,2,3 in $stk

Answer (score 0):

You got a pretty good base to begin with, but there is a small error, you are looping through your sql calls. Where you should be making a comma sepperated list for your IN ($stk).

Take a look at this answer: [How to convert items in array to a comma separated string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936059/how-to-convert-items-in-array-to-a-comma-separated-string-in-php)

so

```
foreach ($name as $stk){
```

should be

```
$stk = implode(',', $name);
```

and remember to remove the last "}" since you don't need that anymore

Comment: implode is correct i can display 1 data but when i choose multiple it display blank..