# Remove last comma after PHP string?

Tags: php, string, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create comma separated list from array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php)

I have a Wordpress site, and i use the plugin Magic Fields. To echo the inputs from the plugin I use these code:

```
<?php 
$my_list = get('startopstilling_test');
foreach($my_list as $element){
echo   $element . ",";
```

}
?>

The code echo this:

Casillas,Albiol,Xabi Alonso,Kaka,

But i would like to remove the last comma that makes it look like this:

Casillas,Albiol,Xabi Alonso,Kaka

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use [`implode(',', $my_list)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Alternatively, `fputcsv`! The possibilities are endless.

Comment: @minitech Doesn't that require a file resource? Or does PHP have something akin to Python's [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)?

Comment: @NullUserException - You could set up a file handle to a stream such as php://temp, and then reset and read the results back into a variable

Comment: @NullUserException: [I'm just being horrible.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/doqtWO) (Substitute `$stdout` for `STDOUT` for console stuff, 'course.)

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead:

```
echo implode(',', $my_list);
```

But if you really want to, you can use `rtrim` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [implode](http://php.net/implode), [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim), or, probably better, use a something like [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode). In its current state, what happens when one of your fields has a comma in it? I suspect things will crash and burn :).

If you do go the route of CSV, you could do it properly with fputcsv:

```
$han = fopen("php://memory", "rw");
fputcsv($someArray);
fseek($han, 0);
echo stream_get_contents($han);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do either:

```
$del = "";
foreach ($my_list as $element)
{
    echo $del . $element;
    $del = ", ";
}
```

or build it all into a string and then use:

```
echo rtrim($string, ",");
```

or even better, just use implode:

```
echo implode(",", $my_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it all into one string and then remove the comma

```
$str="";    
foreach($my_list as $element){
    $str.=$element . ",";}
rtrim($str,',');
echo $str;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate string `$elementstr`

```
<?php 
  $my_list = get('startopstilling_test');

  foreach($my_list as $element){
       $elementstr.= $element . ",";
 } 

 ?>
```

And then

```
echo rtim($elementstr,',');
```

Comment: but faster solution would be to just do implode()