# Build comma separated string in PHP Loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hello Guys i need to do this,

I have a common loop

```
foreach ($stuffs as $stuff) {
echo $stuff;
}
```

Lets assume $stuff is an 'id' of a mysql table what i have and i dont want to be showed in next results, so i want to build a string like this

```
1,23,54,67 (comma separated)
```

So that string will be in mysql query to exclude results that already have been shown.
how can i do that?

Should be with implode? How can i achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create comma separated list from array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[implode](http://php.net/implode) should be the tool:

```
implode(",", $stuffs);
```

will return a comma separated list.

#### Test

```
$myarray=array(1,2,"hello",4,5);
echo implode(",", $myarray);
```

returns

```
1,2,hello,4,5
```

Comment: +1 cannot see what's wrong with this (ps. well, you could use ' instead of ", which in theory would be faster)

Comment: this makes an assumption that $stuffs is already an array, whereas it doesnt have to be that way. It can be something else that is iterable

Comment: @Gadoma - though if $stuffs wasn't an array, OP should have indicated that in their question

Comment: Ops new solution tryin here folks leme check

Comment: @MarkBaker true, true :)

Answer (score 5):

If you really wanna have the loop:

```
$values = "";

foreach ($stuffs as $stuff) {
    $values != "" && $values .= ",";
    $values .= $stuff;
 }

echo $values;
```

I suggest using implode, but the loop can really give you more power if you wanna do some further stuff.

Comment: `Well if you really wanna have the loop` - why would you wanna have the loop in the first place? It's not necessary here. A simple `implode()` would do the job ;)

Comment: Like I said, just gives you more control

Answer (score 3):

This worked in my case (detects if isn't the loop last iteration):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    ...
    if($key!==count($array)-1){echo ',';}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
$string = implode(",",$stuffs);
echo $string
```

Comment: I had simplified it as it was redundant.

Comment: see the comments to the answer of @fedorqui