# transform array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I transform this array:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 25
        [2] => 29
        [3] => 27
        [4] => 24
        [5] => 7
    )
```

into <strike>array</strike> a comma separated string list:

```
6,25,29,27,24,7
```

without altering the order.

My goal and then I get this string array, but I do not know how to do.

Comment: The array you expect is already the original one you have...

Comment: Wait what ? String array ?

Comment: Let us guess in which year this has been asked already first on SO? I assume it was 2009.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create comma separated list from array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php)  (From 2010)

Answer (score 10):

The array is an array already. If you mean you want to turn it into a string, then use the implode function:

```
$string = implode(",", $array);
```

The numbers you are seeing first (eg 0 => 6) show the KEY of the element.

You can access individual elements in your code by that key. For example:

```
echo $array[0];
```

Would output 6 - the value stored in the element with a key of 0.

Answer (score 4):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in php

Try like

```
$arr =  array
    (
        '0' => 6,
        '1' => 25,
        '2' => 29,
        '3' => 27,
        '4' => 24,
        '5' => 7
    );
$newArr = array();
$newArr[0]  = "'".implode("','",$arr)."'";
print_r($newArr);
```

Output

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => '6','25','29','27','24','7'
>   )

Comment: ok and then how can I get a string consists of:
'6', '25', '29', '27', '24', '7'

Comment: See my updated answer @Carla Lo Monte.

Answer (score 1):

```
implode(',',$array)
```

Try to print this.

Comment: ok and then how can I get a string consists of: '6', '25', '29', '27', '24', '7'