# Remove Last Comma From Array Value in Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm storing some data in a "specialties" column of a MySQL db like so:

```
,,specialty1,,,,specialty2,,,,specialty3,
```

First, I take that data and turn it into an array:

```
$specialties = $location['specialties'];
$specialties_array = sw::shared()->users->unserializeArray($specialties);
foreach ($specialties_array as $specialty) {
    $specialty = str_replace(',', '', $specialty);
    echo $specialty . ", "; 
}
```

unSerializeArray function:

```
public function unserializeArray($string) {

    $array = explode(",,",$string);
    unset($array[0]);
    $array = array_values($array);

    return $array;

}
```

My problem with the function above is some of the array values still have a single comma attached to them after that function runs.

So next I use str_replace to remove commas to ensure the specialty value is separated. After separating the specialty value I then re-add a single comma to each specialty for output.

Ideally, I would like to show the specialties without a comma after the last specialty:

```
specialty1, specialty2, specialty3
```

However, it is outputting like this of course:

```
specialty1, specialty2, specialty3,
```

How can I remove the last comma when I am echoing each specialty separately rather than an array as a whole? Is there a better way to do this?

I tried the solution from this thread: [Removing last comma from a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935405/removing-last-comma-from-a-foreach-loop) but I think the way I'm storing the data (,,specialty1,,,,specialty2,,,,specialty3,) is causing an issue with this solution.

Comment: $string = rtrim($string, ',');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode on a single comma, use `array_filter` to remove empty entries, and `implode` to rejoin the values:

```
public function unserializeArray($string) {
    return array_values(array_filter(explode(',' $string)));
}
...
echo implode(',',$sw::shared()->users->unserializeArray($specialties));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$str= rtrim($str, ',');
```