# merge 2 array key values into one key value php

Tags: php, arrays

lets say i have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first one
    [1] => second
)
```

Essentially i want to get both of the values and put them into the same value but separated with a comma.

The desired output would be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first one, second
)
```

I'm not sure what function can achieve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-to-create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Use implode function like :

```
$newArray[] = implode(',' , $array);
```

see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP implode method, like so:

```
implode ( ',' , $array )
```