# How to Send Function multiple phone numbers?

Tags: php

I have write some code for send sms to multiple users with database values i will get the mobile numbers to that code but i will send sms to that only single mobile number msg can passed remain numbers not accepting but i have send the no of mobile numbers are there all members msg will send i will write some code in here once check how to send and also i will try this  code working only one mobile number

in the below code i will get records 2.

mobile numbers are also display 2 values.

sendSMS() function i will placed in while loop and outer while loop but last record will be selected.

```
$get_donor = "SELECT * FROM donor_register WHERE `dnr_bloodgroup` ='$blood_group' and `dnr_city` = '$city' ";
          $get_result = $conn->query($get_donor);
            $count = $get_result->num_rows;

            if($count > 0)
            {
            while($row = $get_result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                  $phone ='';
                  $phone .=$row['dnr_phone']; 
                  echo $phone;
           } 
           sendSMS("Pname",$phone,$message);
         }
```

My sendSMS function like this

```
function sendSMS($sender, $mobile_number, $message)
{
//some code 
}
```

I Expected out put is Pname 3214569870,7412589630,4561237890... this will i will ecpected

But i have get it pname 3214569870 only.

Comment: You have `$phone ='';` inside the while loop.

Comment: but my output look like this 78945612303214569870 but i expected out put is 3214569870,7412589630,4561237890 this way

Comment: If you want commas in between, use `$phone[] = $row['dnr_phone'];`, then `echo join(", ", $phone);`

Comment: @ChrisG seems, ^ it should be the answer :)

Comment: @ChrisG not working the out put look like this error will came  $phone[] = $row['dnr_phone'];
              echo join(", ", $phone);
              Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Before the loop, put `$phone = [];`

Comment: Change your SQL to be `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dnr_phone) AS phone_list FROM donor_register WHERE...`, then it is 1 record with `$row['phone_list']` as the list of numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a comma-separated list from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435216/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: this is another concept and that one is another concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    $phone ='';
    while($row = $get_result->fetch_assoc())
    {

      if($phone && $row['dnr_phone']) {
          $phone .= ',';
        } 
      $phone .=$row['dnr_phone'];
    }
    echo $phone;
```

Answer (score 2):

declare `$phone` variable out side of while loop

```
$phone ='';
while($row = $get_result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                  if($phone) {
                       $phone .=','.$row['dnr_phone']; 
                  } else {
                       $phone .=$row['dnr_phone']; 
                  }

                  echo $phone;
           }
```

Comment: but the out put is look like this 78945612303214569870 result will came but i will expected 3214569870,7412589630,4561237890 this way

Comment: just add comma in loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if($count > 0)
    {   
        $phone ='';
        while($row = $get_result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if($phone==''){
                $phone .=$row['dnr_phone']; 
            }else{
                $phone .=','.$row['dnr_phone']; 
            }
            echo $phone;
        } 
        sendSMS("Pname",$phone,$message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to above code, $phone takes only last mobile number,because sendSMS function called after while loop.

Solution::
sendSMS("Pname",$phone,$message);
This function should be in while loop.

Comment: alredy i will working the after while and in while loop but not working